# How to loop by indexed attribute in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this kind of ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "bee_sesi_edit.php",
        data: 
        'serv_ruang='+ serv_ruangx 
        +'&who='+names 
        +'&sesi_d1='+ sesi_d1 
        +'&sesi_d2='+ sesi_d2 
        +'&sesi_d3='+ sesi_d3 
        +'&sesi_d4='+ sesi_d4 
        +'&sesi_d5='+ sesi_d5
        +'&sesi_d6='+ sesi_d6 
        +'&sesi_d7='+ sesi_d7 
        +'&sesi_d8='+ sesi_d8 
        +'&sesi_d9='+ sesi_d9 
        +'&sesi_d10='+ sesi_d10
        +'&sesi_d11='+ sesi_d11 
        ,
```

I got sesi_d* from getElementbyId, number of iteration is dynamic based on user entry.

I've tried this with no luck

```
var jumlah_hari = document.getElementById('jum_hari').value;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "bee_sesi_edit.php",
    data: 'serv_ruang='+ serv_ruangx +'&who='+names +
    for (var i = 1; i <= jumlah_hari; ++i) {
        eval( '&sesi_d'+i+'=sesi_d' + i +); 
    }
```

Can someone show me to have looping for the sesi_d*, is it possible to do it ?
Thank you so much

Comment: Show more code - where `sesi_d` come from?

Comment: You shoudl really give it a go yourself. Then if you have probelms, show us your code and we can help you fix it

Comment: I don't think looping in ajax is recommended, instead just above ajax why not write a loop which builds data string and pass it to ajax...?

Comment: `sesi_d` should be an array. Then you'd be able to use `$.param` on it.

Comment: all values come from getelementbyId

Comment: @abizayra can you show us the html as well?

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS true, why i make my life so complicated while i can send the iteration as one variable. Thanks for the idea dude

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the global variable by its name using `window["nameOfVar"]`

But it's better to have the object with properties instead of the global variables

```js
// OP's request

const
  serv_ruangx = "test",
  names = ["0", "1"],
  sesi_d1 = "s0",
  sesi_d2 = "s2",
  sesi_d3 = "s3";
  
var data = {
  serv_ruangx,
  who: names,
  ...new Array(3).fill().reduce((obj, _, i) => {
    const name = `sesi_d${i + 1}`
   return { ...obj, [name]: window[name] };
  }, {})
}

$.post("bee_sesi_edit.php", { data })

// Better way

const sesi_d = ["s0", "s1", "s3"];
  
var data = {
  serv_ruangx,
  who: names,
  ...sesi_d.reduce((obj, value, i) => ({ ...obj, [`sesi_d${i + 1}`]: value }), {})
}

$.post("bee_sesi_edit.php", { data })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a variable obj, if you need to iterate it via Javascript, then you just need something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; obj['sesi_d' + i] !== undefined; i++) {
    //Do something
}
```

Or, if you need to do it on server-side (PHP), then do something like this:

```
for ($i = 1; isset($_POST['sesi_d'.$i]); $i++) {
   //Do something
}
```

The idea is that the elements have the same prefix and you only need to change their index in the suffix.

Comment: as I'm beginner in javascript and ajax, can you show me where shall I put that iteration ? i've been trying to put it after data: 
        'serv_ruang='+ serv_ruangx 
        +'&who='+names (start iteration) and its not  working

Comment: @abizayra yes, I can see it and it's nice that you are trying to have some progress. I will need to know how your AJAX is defined in the first place in order to answer your question here in the comment section. If I have either the variable that you work with or the HTML structure to read the data from, then I will be able to help you.